# Javascript function not waiting for function to finish

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a map function that adds all the markers for locations.  However, I've got one spot in my code in which I'm calling a function, but js is not waiting for the response before continuing to run code.  Here's the script in it's entirety.

The problem in question is inside the `getMap()` function on this line of code

`TrialLocationAddress = getTrialLocationGeoCode(TrialLocation.Address);`

I need it to wait here until it gets the address properly before proceeding. I've tried inserting `await` but then it throws and error saying that its only async functions

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var MapID = "googleMap";
    var defaultMapLocation = {
        lat: 40.196409,
        lon: -97.885575,
        zoom: 4.75
    };
    var NewMapOptions;
    var TrialLocations = [
        {
            Name: "Medicine",
            Address: "Address 1, Abington, PA 19046"
        },
        {
            Name: "Boston",
            Address: "Address 2, Waltham, MA 02451"
        }
        ];
    var TrialLocationInfoWindows = [];
    
    function initMap() {

        var gGeoCoder;
        var UserEnteredAddress = '<?php echo ( !empty( $UserEnteredAddress ) ? $UserEnteredAddress : "false"); ?>';
        var MapPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(defaultMapLocation['lat'], defaultMapLocation['lon']);

        if( UserEnteredAddress !== 'false' )
        {
            gGeoCoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            if ( gGeoCoder ) {
                gGeoCoder.geocode({
                    'address': UserEnteredAddress
                }, function (results, status)
                {
                    if ( status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK ) {
                        if ( status !== google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS ) {
                            NewMapOptions = {
                                zoom: 7,
                                center: results[0].geometry.location
                            };
                            getMap(NewMapOptions, results[0]);
                        } else {
                            alert("No location results found");
                        }
                    } else {
                        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                alert( "Geocode encountered an error initializing" );
            }
        } else {
            NewMapOptions = {
                zoom: defaultMapLocation['zoom'],
                center: MapPosition
            };
            getMap( NewMapOptions );
        }
    }

    function getMap( NewMap, SearchLocation = false ) {
        var i = 0;
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(MapID), NewMap);
        var TrialLocationAddress;
        
        if( SearchLocation !== false )
        {
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
                {
                    content: '<b>Your Location:</b> ' + SearchLocation.formatted_address,
                    size: new google.maps.Size(150, 50)
                });
    
            var searchMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: SearchLocation.geometry.location,
                map: map,
                title: SearchLocation.formatted_address,
                icon:{
                    url: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal2/icon13.png"
                }
            });
           
            google.maps.event.addListener( searchMarker, 'click', function () {
                infowindow.open(map, searchMarker);
            });
        }

        TrialLocations.forEach(function(TrialLocation){
            console.log( TrialLocation.Address );
            TrialLocationAddress = getTrialLocationGeoCode(TrialLocation.Address);
            console.log( "AFTER ADDRESS:" + TrialLocationAddress );
            if( TrialLocationAddress !== false && typeof TrialLocationAddress != 'undefined') {
                console.log("trial location address:" + TrialLocationAddress );
                var TrialLocationMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: TrialLocationAddress.geometry.location,
                    map: map,
                    title: TrialLocation.Name
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(TrialLocationMarker, 'click', function (TrialLocation, i) {
                    return function () {
                        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
                            {
                                content: '<b>' + TrialLocation.Name + '</b>',
                                size: new google.maps.Size(150, 50)
                            });
                        infowindow.open(map, TrialLocationMarker);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
    
    function getTrialLocationGeoCode( Address )
    {
        console.log ("init trial geo");
        gGeoCoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        if ( gGeoCoder ) {
            gGeoCoder.geocode({
                'address': Address
            }, function (results, status)
            {
                console.log("inside the function for location geo");
                if ( status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK ) {
                    if ( status !== google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS ) {
                            console.log("inside trialgeo" + results[0] );
                            return results[0];
                    } else {
                        console.log("error 1");
                        return false;
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("error 2");
                    return false;
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.log("error 3");
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={APIKEY}&callback=initMap"></script>
```

```html
<div id="googleMap" style="width: 100%; height:600px;"></div>

<?php
if( array_key_exists( "search", $_POST ) ):
    $UserEnteredAddress = $_POST["search"];
elseif( array_key_exists( "search", $_GET ) ):
    $UserEnteredAddress = $_GET["search"];
else:
    $UserEnteredAddress = "";
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Please read about asynchronous functions - https://eloquentjavascript.net/11_async.html

Comment: *it throws and error saying that its only async functions*  ??? what is the quote-unquote message and where/what line is it being thrown on?

Comment: Video: [Async/Await: Modern Concurrency In JavaScript](https://youtu.be/NsQ2QIrQShU).  And, read [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)

Answer (score 1):

you can go around this through two methods:

## 1 replace map with for-loop

## 2 add a counter that checks if every element has been iterated by the call back function.

Comment: can you give me an example

Comment: im using mobile, so can't code right now. just search Internet using two solutions you'll find it, quite easily.

Comment: bad advice. keep the map function and just pass the iterator as the second param if you really need it (even though this answer isn't the solution to to issue)

Comment: got it working now.  I used a callback as suggested.  I'm posting my fix above

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by adding a callback at the same location that was throwing the error. Thanks to akhilesh. Hope this helps someone else.

```js
function getMap( NewMap, SearchLocation = false ) {
    var i = 0;
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(MapID), NewMap);
    var TrialLocationAddress;

    if( SearchLocation !== false )
    {
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
            {
                content: '<b>Your Location:</b> ' + SearchLocation.formatted_address,
                size: new google.maps.Size(150, 50)
            });

        var searchMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: SearchLocation.geometry.location,
            map: map,
            title: SearchLocation.formatted_address,
            icon:{
                url: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal2/icon13.png"
            }
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener( searchMarker, 'click', function () {
            infowindow.open(map, searchMarker);
        });
    }

    TrialLocations.forEach(function(TrialLocation){
        console.log( TrialLocation.Address );
        getTrialLocationGeoCode(TrialLocation, function( pGeo, pLocation ){
            if( pGeo !== false && typeof pGeo != 'undefined') {
                var TrialLocationMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: pGeo.geometry.location,
                    map: map,
                    title: pLocation.Name
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(TrialLocationMarker, 'click', function (TrialLocation, i) {
                    return function () {
                        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
                            {
                                content: '<b>' + pLocation.Name + '</b>',
                                size: new google.maps.Size(150, 50)
                            });
                        infowindow.open(map, TrialLocationMarker);
                    }
                });
            }
        });


    });
}
    
function getTrialLocationGeoCode( pLocation, callback )
{
    console.log ("init trial geo");
    gGeoCoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    if ( gGeoCoder ) {
        gGeoCoder.geocode({
            'address': pLocation.Address
        }, function (results, status)
        {
            console.log("inside the function for location geo");
            if ( status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK ) {
                if ( status !== google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS ) {
                        console.log("inside trialgeo" + results[0] );
                    callback( results[0] , pLocation);
                } else {
                    console.log("error 1");
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                console.log("error 2");
                return false;
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log("error 3");
        return false;
    }
}
```